# Is there a function which has limit only given $a_1,a_2...a_n....$ infinite points.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Find a *function* which has limit only in advanced marked points$(a_1,a_2,....a_n)$.

Here is my example.

$g(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if}~x\in\mathbb{Q} \\
0, & \text{if}~x\in\Bbb{R}\backslash \Bbb{Q}
\end{cases}$

$f(x) = (x-a_1)(x-a_2)...(x-a_n)g(x)$

But the problem I can't solve is that,is there a function which has limit only in advanced  given $a_1,a_2...a_n....$ infinite points.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. What is the expected behavior between the points?

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67620/set-of-continuity-points-of-a-real-function

Comment: This is extremely unclear. Can you define the concepts in your post?

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent way of asking this question is whether there exists a function which is **continuous** only on a given sequence.

Such a function may fail to exists, for example when your sequence is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ (e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$). Because the set of continuity points must be a $G_\delta$ subset (and therefore cannot be dense and countable).

On the other hand, if your sequence has no limit points, then one can easily construct such a function by dividing $\mathbb{R}$ into intervals, each containing a single element of the sequence, and then define the function on the each interval to be continuous only on that element (for example as you suggested in your question).

Comment: Why are both questions equivalent? What if the limit exists at some points $a_i$ but the function is not continuous at that points?

Comment: @jjagmath . I agree. The Q asks whether there exists $f$ such that $\lim_{y\to x}f(y)$  exists iff $x\in\{a_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, not that $\lim_{y\to x}f(y)=f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your statement, then as stated this is not possible. You need some further hypothesis on the sequence $(a_n)$.

Otherwise take $a_n$ to be an enumeration of the rationals. If $f$ satisfies your condition then by assigning at each $a_n$ the limit value to $f(a_n)$ you obtain a function which is continuous on the rationals and discontinuous on irrationals. This is not possibly by
[Baire's category theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567694/prove-that-there-doesnt-exist-any-function-f-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-r-that-is-c).

When the sequence has no accumulation
points there are several ways. You could e.g. use Weierstrass' [Factorization Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem)
which states that given any sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ of complex numbers, with $|a_n|\to \infty$, there is an
entire function $h(z)$ whose zeroes are exactly the elements of the sequence (see e.g. the link).
Then your argument taking your $g$ and $f(z)=h(z)g(z)$ still goes through.
But this may violate your requirement of 'not using series'?

Comment: The trouble with this A is that the Q asks that $\lim_{x\to a_n}f(x)$ exists but not that $f$ is necessarily continuous at $a_n$. Some other answers  also have this oversight.

Comment: Thanks, but I am aware of this. I explicitly state that BY ASSIGNING the limit value at each $a_n$, then you obtain a function which is continuous at $a_n$ and discontinuous everywhere else. And for this there are counterexamples (as also stated by @MOMO).

Answer (score -3):

Assume that there is an order preserving bijection between $a_n$ and N.
Define
$$ f(x)=\frac{1}{n}, \quad x \in[a_n, a_{n+1}).
$$

Then the function is discontinuous at every $a_n$ but has a right limit as $x \to a_n$.
If, however, you want double-sided limits then take a small $\delta$ and modify as
$f(x)=\frac{1}{n}$ for x $\in(a_n-\delta, a_{n}+\delta)$ and $f(x)=i$ inbeween (imaginary).
But in this case, you are going outside ot the real numbers.
From the perspective of the real numbers, the function is undefined between the intervals.

Comment: This only work if the sequence $(a_n)$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: @ jjagmath. Not true. Think before you downvote. Do you know the definition of a limit?

Comment: @user48672 He is correct, it is not a function otherwise.

Comment: @Dole A function is a mapping between 2 sets. So the pre-image set must be specified. I can take $R \to R$ but also $R - > C$. What is wanted to point out is that the question underspecified.

Comment: I think their point is that, if $a_2<a_4<a_3<a_5$, then your function is defined so that $f(x)=1/2=1/4$ for $a_4<x<a_3$

Comment: As in, although the points $a_n$ are countable, there may not exist an order preserving bijection with the set of points and $\mathbb{N}$ that allows $f(x)$ to be defined piecewise on disjoint intervals $[a_n,a_{n+1})$

Comment: The definition holds, as long as the intervals are disjoint, which is the case in my definition. so in any case $f(x)=1/2$ for $[a_2, a_4)$ and f(x)=1/4 for  $[a_4, a_3)$ and $f(x)=1/3$ for $[a_3, a_5)$.

Comment: Then I think you should start your answer by saying “If there is an order preserving bijection between $\{a_n\}$ and $\mathbb{N}$, then define $f(x)=$...”, since otherwise you cannot definite the intervals $[a_n, a_{n+1})$ to be disjoint.